# Substrate: "cargo build --release" in Windows, honggfuzz-rs does not currently support Windows but works well under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, substrate

When I use the command `cargo build --release` in Windows, it shows problem:

> honggfuzz-rs does not currently support Windows but works well under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Does any one have solved this problem before? Does it means I must use Linux System run Substrate?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that Windows development is fully supported at this time. [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) will allow you to run a Linux environment inside your Windows operating system and I have heard people say it works very well for Substrate development. As a workaround at this time, can you please try executing the following command to only build the Substrate and skip the fuzzing step that requires the problematic dependency? `cargo build -p node-cli --release`